# Crash saving buttontoggle state

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, onclicklistener, togglebutton

I'm trying to save the state of a toggle button but i get a crash.. I'm using a fragment so i created the code in this way:

```
public class fragmentbutton extends Fragment {

    public ToggleButton onOff;
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // Retrieving the currently selected item number
            int position = getArguments().getInt("position");
            // List of rivers
            String[] menus = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menus);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentbutton, container, false);

             final SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
             boolean tgpref = preferences.getBoolean("tgpref", true);  //default is true
             if (tgpref = true) //if (tgpref) may be enough, not sure
             {
                 onOff.setChecked(true);
             }
             else
             {
                 onOff.setChecked(false);
             }

             retrieveFromDb();

                onOff = (ToggleButton)v.findViewById(R.id.onoff);
                onOff.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        if(isChecked == true){
                            getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(),NotificationService.class));

                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                            editor.putBoolean("tgpref", true); // value to store
                            editor.commit();
                        }else {
                            getActivity().stopService(new Intent(getActivity(),NotificationService.class));

                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                            editor.putBoolean("tgpref", false); // value to store
                            editor.commit();
                        }
                    }
                });
            return v;

        }
---
---
```

the logcat:

```
12-12 22:45:18.836: E/AndroidRuntime(23007): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 22:45:18.836: E/AndroidRuntime(23007): Process: com.dd.allinonesystempro, PID: 23007
12-12 22:45:18.836: E/AndroidRuntime(23007): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 22:45:18.836: E/AndroidRuntime(23007):    at com.dd.allinonesystempro.batteryfragment.onCreateView(batteryfragment.java:114)
12-12 22:45:18.836: E/AndroidRuntime(23007):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
12-12 22:45:18.836: E/AndroidRuntime(23007):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
12-12 22:45:18.836: E/AndroidRuntime(23007):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
12-12 22:45:18.836: E/AndroidRuntime(23007):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
12-12 22:45:18.836: E/AndroidRuntime(23007):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
12-12 22:45:18.836: E/AndroidRuntime(23007):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
12-12 22:45:18.836: E/AndroidRuntime(23007):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-12 22:45:18.836: E/AndroidRuntime(23007):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-12 22:45:18.836: E/AndroidRuntime(23007):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-12 22:45:18.836: E/AndroidRuntime(23007):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-12 22:45:18.836: E/AndroidRuntime(23007):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 22:45:18.836: E/AndroidRuntime(23007):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-12 22:45:18.836: E/AndroidRuntime(23007):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-12 22:45:18.836: E/AndroidRuntime(23007):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-12 22:45:18.836: E/AndroidRuntime(23007):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What do you have in line 114 in batteryfragment?

Comment: this: `onOff.setChecked(true);` what i posted is only a part of the batteryfragment. Don't care about the fragment name in this post.. I wanted display the button and the sharedpreferences i used in particular way.. How can i solve?

Comment: It's look like it something wrong in this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `onOff` is null.

You are trying to set onOff first which is null and then after few lines trying to set

```
onOff = (ToggleButton)v.findViewById(R.id.onoff);
```

move this line up before you try to access onOff.

also `if (tgpref = true)` should be `if (tgpref == true)`

Comment: Only one another thing.. I set in this way the button now : `boolean tgpref = preferences.getBoolean("tgpref", false);` so it would starts in false state.. But it starts in true.. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize your `onOff` view before calling `setChecked()` on it:

```
onOff = (ToggleButton)v.findViewById(R.id.onoff);

if (tgpref == true) //if (tgpref) may be enough, not sure
{
    onOff.setChecked(true);
}
else
{
    onOff.setChecked(false);
}
```

Comment: Only one another thing.. I set in this way the button now : `boolean tgpref = preferences.getBoolean("tgpref", false);` so it would starts in false state.. But it starts in true.. Why?

Comment: most likely because you have saved a preference value (`true`) on a previous run of your app. Try uninstalling or cleaning the data of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to change:

```
 if (tgpref = true)
```

to:

```
 if (tgpref == true)
```

To compare you have to use ==.

Comment: Okey, post your new logcat

Comment: same logcat i posted :(